# How user can (safely) programme their own filter in Java

Tags: java, dynamic, groovy, rhino

I want my users to be able to write there own filter when requesting a List in Java.

**Option 1)** I'm thinking about JavaScript with Rhino.
I get my user's filter as a javascript string. And then call `isAccepted(myItem)` in this script.
Depending on the reply I accept the element or not.

**Option 2)** I'm thinking about Groovy.
My user can write Groovy script in a textfield. When my user searches with this filter the Groovy script is compiled in Java (if first call) and call the Java methode `isAccepted()`
Depending on the reply I accept the element or not.

My application rely a lot on this fonctionallity and it will be called intensively on my server.
So I beleave speed is the key.

**Option 1 thinking:**
Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think in my case the main advantage of Groovy is the speed but my user can compile and run unwanted code on my server... (any workaround?)

**Option 2 thinking:**
I think in most people mind JavaScript is more like a toy. Even if it's not my idea **at all** it is probably for my customers who will not trust it that much. Do you think so?
An other bad point I expect is speed, from my reading on the web.
And again my user can [access Java](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/ScriptingJava.html) and run unwanted code on my server... (any workaround?)

More info:
I'm running my application on Google App Engine for the main web service of my app.
The filter will be apply 20 times by call.
The filter will be (most of the times) simple.

Any idea to make this filter safe for my server?
Any other approche to make it work?

Comment: Your question is too vague, and btw anyone who considers Javascript to be just a toy is very out of touch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My thoughts:

- You'll have to use your own classloader when compiling your script, to avoid any other classes to be accessible from the script. Not sure if that is possible in GAE.
- You'll have to use Java's SecurityManager features to avoid a script being able to access the file ssystem, network, etc etc. Not sure if that is possible in GAE.

Looking only at the two items above, it looks incredibly complicated and brittle to me. If you can't find existing sandboxing features as an existing project, you should stay away from it.

Designing a Domain Specific Language that will allow the expressions you decide are legal is a lot safer, and looking at the above items, you will have to think very hard anyway at what you want to allow. From there to designing the language is not a big step.

Be careful not to implement the DSL with groovy closures (internal DSL), because that is just groovy and you are hackable too. You need to define an extrnal language and parse it. I recommend the parser combinator jparsec to define the grammar. no compiler compiler needed in that case.

http://jparsec.codehaus.org/

FYI, here's a little parser I wrote with jparsec (groovy code):

```
    //import some static methods, this will allow more concise code
    import static org.codehaus.jparsec.Parsers.*
    import static org.codehaus.jparsec.Terminals.*
    import static org.codehaus.jparsec.Scanners.*

    import org.codehaus.jparsec.functors.Map as FMap
    import org.codehaus.jparsec.functors.Map4 as FMap4
    import org.codehaus.jparsec.functors.Map3 as FMap3
    import org.codehaus.jparsec.functors.Map2 as FMap2

    /**
     * Uses jparsec combinator parser library to construct an external DSL parser for the following grammar:
     * <pre>
     *     pipeline := routingStep*
     *     routingStep := IDENTIFIER '(' parameters? ')'
     *     parameters := parameter (',' parameter)*
     *     parameter := (IDENTIFIER | QUOTED_STRING)  ':' QUOTED_STRING
     * </pre>
     */
    class PipelineParser {
        //=======================================================
        //Pass 1: Define which terminals are part of the grammar
        //=======================================================
        //operators
        private static def OPERATORS = operators(',', '(', ')', ':')
        private static def LPAREN = OPERATORS.token('(')
        private static def RPAREN = OPERATORS.token(')')
        private static def COLON = OPERATORS.token(':')
        private static def COMMA = OPERATORS.token(',')

        //identifiers tokenizer
        private static def IDENTIFIER = Identifier.TOKENIZER
        //single quoted strings tokenizer
        private static def SINGLE_QUOTED_STRING = StringLiteral.SINGLE_QUOTE_TOKENIZER

        //=======================================================
        //Pass 2: Define the syntax of the grammar
        //=======================================================
        //PRODUCTION RULE: parameter := (IDENTIFIER | QUOTED_STRING) ':' QUOTED_STRING
        @SuppressWarnings("GroovyAssignabilityCheck")
        private static def parameter = sequence(or(Identifier.PARSER,StringLiteral.PARSER), COLON, StringLiteral.PARSER, new FMap3() {
            def map(paramName, colon, paramValue) {
                new Parameter(name: paramName, value: paramValue)
            }
        })

        //PRODUCTION RULE: parameters := parameter (',' parameter)*
        @SuppressWarnings("GroovyAssignabilityCheck")
        private static def parameters = sequence(parameter, sequence(COMMA, parameter).many(), new FMap2() {
            def map(parameter1, otherParameters) {
                if (otherParameters != null) {
                    [parameter1, otherParameters].flatten()
                } else {
                    [parameter1]
                }
            }
        })

        //PRODUCTION RULE: routingStep := IDENTIFIER '(' parameters? ')'
        @SuppressWarnings("GroovyAssignabilityCheck")
        private static def routingStep = sequence(Identifier.PARSER, LPAREN, parameters.optional(), RPAREN, new FMap4() {
            def map(routingStepName, lParen, parameters, rParen) {
                new RoutingStep(
                    name: routingStepName,
                    parameters: parameters ?: []
                )
            }
        })

        //PRODUCTION RULE: pipeline := routingStep*
        @SuppressWarnings("GroovyAssignabilityCheck")
        private static def pipeline = routingStep.many().map(new FMap() {
            def map(from) {
                new Pipeline(
                    routingSteps: from
                )
            }
        })

        //Combine the above tokenizers to create the tokenizer that will parse the stream and spit out the tokens of the grammar
        private static def tokenizer = or(OPERATORS.tokenizer(), SINGLE_QUOTED_STRING, IDENTIFIER)

        //This parser will be used to define which input sequences need to be ignored
        private static def ignored = or(JAVA_LINE_COMMENT, JAVA_BLOCK_COMMENT, WHITESPACES)

        /**
         * Parser that is used to parse extender pipelines.
         * <pre>
         *     def parser=PipelineParser.parser
         *     Pipeline pipeline=parser.parse(pipelineStr)
         * </pre>
         * Returns an instance of {@link Pipeline} containing the AST representation of the parsed string.
         */
        //Create a syntactic pipeline parser that will use the given tokenizer to parse the input into tokens, and will ignore sequences that are matched by the given parser.
        static def parser = pipeline.from(tokenizer, ignored.skipMany())
    }
```

Comment: thank you. I started looking in this direction and it look like the best solution. Yes it's possible to setup a sandbox with groovy on app engine. It's what this project is doing: http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/ try to delete a file and you get a security exception !

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts:

- Whether you use JavaScript or Groovy, it will be run in a context that you provide to the script, so the script should not be able to access anything that you don't want it to (but of course, you should test it extensively to be sure if go this route).
- You'd probably be safer by having the filter expression specified as data, rather than as executable code, if possible. Of course, this depends on how complex the filter expressions are. Perhaps you can break up the representation into something like field, comparator, and value, or something similar, that can be treated as data and evaluated in regular way?
- If you're worried about what the user can inject via a scripting language, you're probably safer with JavaScript. I don't think that performance should be a problem, but again, I'd suggest extensive testing to be sure.

Comment: Surely with [the `SecureASTCustomizer`](http://www.jroller.com/melix/entry/customizing_groovy_compilation_process), Groovy is as safe, if not safer (at least more customizable)?

Answer (score 0):

I would never let users input arbitrary code. It's brittle, insecure and a bad user experience. Not knowing anything about your users, my guess is that you will spend a lot of time answering questions.. If most of your filters are simple, why not create a little filter builder for them instead?

As far as groovy vs JavaScript i think groovy is easier to understand and better for scripting but that's just my opinion.